# js window.history.go(-1), window.history.back по разному срабатывает в Chrome и в FF?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добр.день! Нужен возврат из  следующей странице на определенный тэг в index.html. Пытался history.back во всех видах (history.go(-1), history.back, window.history.go(-1), window.history.back...) в FF нормально возвращает к месту перехода, в Chrome перегружает index.html и уходит к началу странице. Классический якорь без js в Chrome сперва возвращает куда надо, затем перегружает страницу...
3 рою Интернет...нашел что механизм кэширования страниц в FF и в Chrome разный...как побороть Chrome, а заодно safari и android не понял(((( помогите пжлста!!!!

Comment: в FF и по браузерному back все как надо...в Chrome перезагрузка по браузерному back...? Почему?

Comment: нет ответа на простой вопрос...жаль